# Javascript jQuery closing bracket error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want my output to be in order like:

```
console.log("1st 1:", y1, y2, y3, y4);
console.log("1st 2:", y1, y2, y3, y4);
console.log("2nd 1:", y1, y2, y3, y4);
console.log("2nd 2:", y1, y2, y3, y4);
console.log("3rd:", y1, y2, y3, y4);
```

But I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` in the `done` statement.

And only be able to see:

```
1st 1: 5 5 5 5
1st 2: 8 30 236 365
```

I can't find anything wrong with this code:

```
    data: (
        function() {

            // Test
            y1 = 5,
            y2 = 5,
            y3 = 5,
            y4 = 5;

            // Ajax is asynchronous
            function doRun() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/getTest",
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log("1st 1:", y1, y2, y3, y4);
                        y1 = data.V1;
                        y2 = data.V2;
                        y3 = data.V3;
                        y4 = data.V4;
                        console.log("1st 2:", y1, y2, y3, y4);
                    }
                });
                return doRun;
            };

            doRun().done(function() {
                console.log("2nd 1", y1, y2, y3, y4);
            }).fail(function() {
                console.log("2nd 2");
            });

            var data = [],
                time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                i;
            for (i = -10; i <= 0; i++) {
                console.log("3rd:", y1, y2, y3, y4);
                data.push({
                    x: time + i * 10,
                    y: 0
                });
            }
            return data;
        }()
    )
```

What should I do fix this problem and printing everything in order?

Comment: Note that the title of the question has no relation to the actual problem. Might want to edit that part!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function doRun() {
                return $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/getTest",
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log("1st 1:", y1, y2, y3, y4);
                        y1 = data.V1;
                        y2 = data.V2;
                        y3 = data.V3;
                        y4 = data.V4;
                        console.log("1st 2:", y1, y2, y3, y4);
                    }
                });
            };
```

You were returning the wrong thing. You returned `doRun` -- the same function that was called. `doRun` does not have a `done` property. You meant to return the promise from `$.ajax`.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to doRun() is returning the doRun function object.  Does that actually have a done() method defined on it?  I'm guessing not.